# decide if use celery or not at runtime

Tags: python, django, metaprogramming, celery, django-celery

I would like to be able to decide if I should execute a function synchroniuosly or asynchroniusly at runtime so I wrote the following code:

```
class DefaultUseCeleryPolicy(UseCeleryPolicy):
    def use(self):
        return anyCeleryWorkerRunning() or FORCE_CELERY

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class TaskDispatcher(object):
    def __init__(self, usePolicy):
        self.usePolicy = usePolicy

    def dispatch(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class CeleryTaskDispatcher(TaskDispatcher):
    def __init__(self, usePolicy = DefaultUseCeleryPolicy()):
        super(CeleryTaskDispatcher, self).__init__(usePolicy)

    def dispatch(self, function, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.usePolicy.use():
            t = task(function)
            tasks.register(t)
            t.delay(args, kwargs)
        else:
            function(args, kwargs)
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work (I'm getting "Received unregistered task of type" error from celery worker). Is it possible to achieve what I want at all?

Comment: Full traceback might be helpful.

Comment: Sure: http://pastebin.com/nC1T0MAx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the is_eager argument and pass that in to the .delay on an as needed basis:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context

So you would do something like:

```
kwargs = {is_eager:False} #runs async
```

later gets set to True depending on criteria:

```
kwargs = {is_eager:True} #runs sync
```

do some more stuff

```
name_of_task.delay(your_arg,**kwargs)
```

Comment: I can change if.. else... part to use is_eager, but I'm sure the code will still be broken. the real problem is how to generate and register new tasks at runtime inside a function. I admit that I realised the essnce of the problem just now so the question in title is a bit misleading...

Comment: Why do you need to have the task registered at times and not at other times?

Comment: Lets say I have many functions in my project. I don't know all of them, I don't want to put them in one file named tasks.py because they are really different. I need something that will take any function and decide in runtime to run it synchronously or not.